# Django 1.7 getting ImportError, Cannot import name patterns

Tags: python, django

Right now when I attempt to do `makemigrations`, I get the infamous `cannot import names pattern` message, upon reviewing my `urls.py` file. I've been searching online for a potential solution given that I am working in Django 1.7, but I haven't found success. I still don't know why this is happening on my current version of django at all and any possible explanation on what could be causing it would be appreciated.

In my urls.py file I have

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
from new_bridge import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', views.IndexView, name='index'),
url(r'^admin/import', views.myimport),
(r'^favicon\.ico$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/static/images/bridge_favicon.ico')),
url(r'^words_page_redirect/(?P<language>[a-zA-Z]+)/$', views.words_page_redirect),....
)
```

and the final line of the message I get on terminal is simply

```
File "/srv/bridge-repo/new_bridge/urls.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
```

Please let me know what other info I could provide to be of more help. Any input on what I could do to actually learn more about this issue, alongside resolve it, is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you are using Django 1.7? django.conf.urls.patterns() is removed in Django 1.10. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.8/#django-conf-urls-patterns

Answer (score 1):

In Django 1.7, you should be able to import `patterns` from `django.conf.urls`. Is it possible you are on a newer version of Django?

Also, the use of `patterns` is deprecated since Django 1.8, so you can actually just avoid using it and replace your code with

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView, name='index'),
    url(r'^admin/import', views.myimport),
    url(r'^favicon\.ico$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/static/images/bridge_favicon.ico')),
    url(r'^words_page_redirect/(?P<language>[a-zA-Z]+)/$', views.words_page_redirect),....
]
```

Note: make sure that each entry is wrapped with the `url` function with this approach.